Why does the Playstore console give a warning even though I have given advertising permission (permission.AD_ID) to the AndroidManifest.xml file?
I am using Google Admob with Flutter. In the AndroidManifest.xml file, the tag <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/> is added.
In the App content in the Play Console policies and programs section, the Advertising ID is selected as yes.
Although the tag is added in the AndroidManifest.xml file, after installing Appbundle and clicking next, when I submit a new version, I get the warning "your advertising id declaration in the play console indicates that your app uses advertising ids. the manifest file in one of your active builds does not contain the com.google.android.gms.permission.ad_id permission."
How can I solve this problem?

Please check if you have an older version in other release track, for example internal testing without AD_ID declaration in the manifest file.
